# Why does the second JFrame does not show components?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jprogressbar

I have the first JFrame and it works fine. When I push a button it is supposed to show a JProgressBar frame , but i get empty JFrame. I open it with

```
                p = new Progress("1/3");
                p.setMax(2);
                p.setProgress(0, "Getting bytes...");
```

Anyone know why?

**EDIT:**
I am going to explain more detail(Because someone misunderstood and corrected my post in the wrong way) - On my main class i start the first JFrame:
`new Crypt();`
And in the Crypt class i have registered a button ActionListener. OnClick it opens a second JFrame **But it is empty**:

```
                p = new Progress("1/3");
                p.setMax(2);
                p.setProgress(0, "Getting bytes...");
```

[The Progress class](http://pastebin.com/SzxpWwnt)
[Screen shot](http://s2.postimg.org/jejoqfebd/Untitled.png)

Comment: `When i push a button it is supposed to show a JProgressBar` please show us that piece of code. Do you use action listeners for this?

Comment: Last time someone had `static` GUI components; hence shared field variables by both frames.

Comment: where you have a button and where is your listener?

Comment: It opens the frame - the button works. But It is empty.

Comment: works for me, with catchable repaint from code lines p.setMax(2);
        p.setProgress(0, "Getting bytes...");

Comment: I have tried it works if it is the only frame. But when i put another one the second one is empty. (Anything i put doesn't show up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in the Crypt class i have registered a button ActionListener. OnClick it opens a second JFrame But it is empty

Code invoked from an Swing listener executes on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. The EDT is responsible for painting Swing components. Since your code is executing a long running task on the EDT y9ou are preventing Swing from painting the component until the task is finished.

You need to start a separate Thread for your long running task. Or better yet you should probably be using a `SwingWorker`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) which explains this in more detail and provides a working example of a SwingWorker.

Comment: Going to try - I am away from Internet but I have docs downloaded